# Validar si una fecha en formato Epoch esta en uno de los rangos

Tags: ionic-framework, posix, angular11

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con **Ionic5/Angular11** y una de las funcionalidades es mostrar las comidas referentes a una una categoría según un rango de horas:

| Categoría | Inicio del rango | Fin del rango |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Desayuno | 03h | 12h |
| Comida | 12h | 18h |
| Cena | 18h | 03h |

La parte complicada es lograr cumplir con **una** de estas restricciones de horarios y que no se solapen entre ellas.

Estoy utilizando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando la respuesta que me dio **@donato-bencosme** actualizo la mia con el fin de cumplir con el requisito principal que es el trabajo con el formato de fechas Epoch.

1. Cree un método para convertir el tiempo a epoch dependiendo de un parámetro requerido y los demás opcionales. Divido entre 1000 el resultado pues estoy interesado solamente en la precisión de segundos.

```js
export class EpochTime {
    public static getEpochTime(hours: number, minutes: number = 0, sec: number = 0, ms: number = 0) {
        return (new Date()).setHours(hours, minutes, sec, ms) / 1000;
    }
}
```

2. Implemento la optimización del código y agrego el uso del método creado para retornar el resultado esperado comparando las fechas en formato Epoch

```js
setCategoryType() {
        let categoryType = 'dinner';
        const hour = (new Date()).setMinutes(0, 0, 0);
        if (hour >= EpochTime.getEpochTime(3) && hour < EpochTime.getEpochTime(12)) {
            categoryType = 'breakfast';
        } else if (hour >= EpochTime.getEpochTime(12) && hour < EpochTime.getEpochTime(18)) {
            categoryType = 'lunch';
        }
    }

return categoryType;
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu código cumple con lo requerido, aunque puedes reducir las cantidad de if que utilizas realizando lo siguiente.

```
 private static getEpochTime(hours: number, minutes: number = 0, sec: number = 0, ms: number = 0) {
            return (new Date()).setHours(hours, minutes, sec, ms);
        }

    function setCategoryType(date){
         let category  = 'Dinner';
        const hour = (new Date()).setMinutes(0, 0, 0);
        if (hour >= CLASS.getEpochTime(3) && hour < CLASS.getEpochTime(12)) {
            category = 'breakfast';
        } else if (hour >= CLASS.getEpochTime(12) && hour < CLASS.getEpochTime(18)) {
            category = 'lunch';
        }

return category;
    }
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.